# Integrating MaltParser into java code, without using a separate process

Tags: java, parsing, nlp

There are several resources already available for training and executing the grammatical dependency parser, MaltParser; most notably is the project's homepage: http://www.maltparser.org/userguide.html#startusing). And looking at the NLTK code that uses MaltParser, I see how I could write equivalent Java code to start up a separate child process to run MaltParser: http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/malt.html. However, what I am asking, or rather looking for, is code that clearly and cleanly shows how to integrate MaltParser as a library into a Java program.

To be specific, I want to write Java code to do the following:

1. Train a parsing model.
2. Load a trained model and parse sentences in an online fashion (i.e. stream sentences and use a MaltParser object to parse each one).

To whomever has the knowledge, patience, and willingness: please to help me answer 1 and 2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a rudimentary solution to 2. I noticed that on http://www.maltparser.org/userguide.html#api it directs one to a listing of example files. I took this snippet out of one of those files:

```
/**
* @author Johan Hall
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        MaltParserService service =  new MaltParserService();
        // Inititalize the parser model 'model0' and sets the working directory to '.' and sets the logging file to 'parser.log'
        service.initializeParserModel("-c model0 -m parse -w . -lfi parser.log");

        // Creates an array of tokens, which contains the Swedish sentence 'Grundavdraget upphör alltså vid en taxerad inkomst på 52500 kr.'
        // in the CoNLL data format.
        String[] tokens = new String[11];
        tokens[0] = "1\tGrundavdraget\t_\tN\tNN\tDD|SS";
        tokens[1] = "2\tupphör\t_\tV\tVV\tPS|SM";
        tokens[2] = "3\talltså\t_\tAB\tAB\tKS";
        tokens[3] = "4\tvid\t_\tPR\tPR\t_";
        tokens[4] = "5\ten\t_\tN\tEN\t_";
        tokens[5] = "6\ttaxerad\t_\tP\tTP\tPA";
        tokens[6] = "7\tinkomst\t_\tN\tNN\t_";
        tokens[7] = "8\tpå\t_\tPR\tPR\t_";
        tokens[8] = "9\t52500\t_\tR\tRO\t_";
        tokens[9] = "10\tkr\t_\tN\tNN\t_";
        tokens[10] = "11\t.\t_\tP\tIP\t_";
        // Parses the Swedish sentence above
        DependencyStructure graph = service.parse(tokens);
        // Outputs the dependency graph created by MaltParser.
        System.out.println(graph);
        // Terminates the parser model
        service.terminateParserModel();
    } catch (MaltChainedException e) {
        System.err.println("MaltParser exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```